# how to add class when multiple class exists with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want in only one area where I clicked

Html:

```html
<div class="sub">
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa like"></i>  
    </div>
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa dislike"></i>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub">
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa like"></i>  
    </div>
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa dislike"></i>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub">
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa like"></i>  
    </div>
    <div class="ar1" >
        <i class="fa dislike"></i>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ar1 > i.like", function(){
    $like = $(this);
    $dislike = $(".ar1 > i.dislike");

    $like.addClass("a1");
    $dislike.addClass("a2"); // this add class in every where, I want in only one area where I clicked
});
```

---

`$dislike.addClass("a2")` add class in every where. I want in only one area where I clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the parent `div.sub` of the field that is clicked using [`$.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector), and then find the `i.dislike` element below that to change its class:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ar1 > i.like", function() {
  $like = $(this);
  $dislike = $(this).closest("div.sub").find("i.dislike");

  $like.addClass("a1");
  $dislike.addClass("a2");
});
```

```css
.a1 {
  color: green;
}

.a2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub">
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa like">Like</i>
  </div>
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa dislike">Dislike</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sub">
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa like">Like</i>
  </div>
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa dislike">Dislike</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sub">
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa like">Like</i>
  </div>
  <div class="ar1">
    <i class="fa dislike">Dislike</i>
  </div>
</div>
```